Washing the clothes in half dirty water make the clothes dirty or clean?
Well, I was just wondering about whether the clothes will get more dirty or more clean when I wash it in half dirty water, I know somewhat that the dirt particles would increase the entropy when being transferred from clothes to water, which means ideally we should be able to wash clothes in any amount of dirty water.(But I don't think that's the case or is it )
I might be wrong tho( I am not quite sure )

Plus one for originality! But it's not really a physics question. I recommend a stack exchange related to housekeeping or DIY

This question will likely be closed for lack of details and clarify. Please, edit to make the physics point more clear and add a reference for the role of entropy when cleaning (or expand it if ir's an original thought).

@RC_23 actually this is a physics question with a good physics answer, in fact, one that you gave as an answer yourself. What is really going to happen is that there is an equivalent of chemical potential, in the form of dirtiness, that will be statistically driven by entropy to be equal between the water and the clothes, and thus the equilibrium will be achieved with equal average dirtiness between the water and the clothes at the end. When the water is too dirty, then it will make the clothes dirtier. Statistical thermodynamics governs way too many phenomena that we can discuss.

Washing clothes in "half dirty" water causes the dirt-level of the clothing and the dirt-level of the water to move toward an equilibrium. Whether that means the clothes get cleaner and the water gets dirtier or vice versa depends on the relative amounts of dirt in the clothing and in the water at the start of the process.

Everyone so far seems to be treating “dirt” as a collection of single molecules, “clothes” as an open region that accepts all substances and preferentially bonds with/excludes none, and detergent, say, as nonexistent. One could arguably write a book to answer the broad question of how laundry works, and this suggests that the question should be clarified to better suit the site.

Entropy, to the extent it plays a role here at all, will push for everything to be equally mixed and evenly distributed everywhere.  So it will push for equal dirt in the water, on the cloth, everything.
